# Using QApplication in a non blocking way

Tags: qt

I want to use 'connect', but if I write

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
connect ....
a.exec();
```

I get blocked after the last command (`a.exec`). But if I don't use this command, then the callbacks don't work.

It is important to say that I don't open any window. All I want to work is the 'connect' option.

Comment: Could you please provide some more code. As exec should run all callbackds, connected to the QtSlots, there must be a problem within the code.

Comment: And by `connect` you mean Qt's signals and slots?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem - what are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to call `app.exec()`.  What you can do instead is periodically call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`.  However this is not recommended unless you're porting a non-Qt app.  A lot of functionality in Qt depends on the event loop, and you will run into problems if you try and bypass it.  It's a better idea to make your own code work with the event loop if possible.

Comment: thanks but I'm using an opensource code which uses QWidget, with forces me to use QApplication

Comment: Of course.  The approach I'm suggesting still involves creating a `QApplication`, you just don't call `exec()` on it.  Instead you run your own loop and call `processEvents()` as appropriate.  This is what the app I'm currently working on had to do for porting to Qt and although not ideal, it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Use QCoreApplication instead of QApplication if you're not using a GUI.

Sorry, not a good answer.

You should consider moving your connect into something in the Qt main event loop.  If that's really not an option, you probably need to spin off another thread which runs the QCoreApplication call.

Comment: thanks but I'm using an opensource code which uses QWidget, with forces me to use QApplication